# FluentValidation MVC Required Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm creating UserValidator to validate UserViewModel using FluentValidation MVC 5

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<UserViewModel>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(u => u.UserName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(1, 50);
        RuleFor(u => u.Password)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(6, 20);
        // How to validate Role must be selected from dropdownlist?
    }
}

UserViewModel
- UserID - int
- Username - varchar(50)
- Password - varchar(20)
- RoleID - int
```

How to create `RuleFor` for `RoleID`, that user must select the role before submit?
If using `DataAnnotation`, I can simply use `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: RuleFor(x => x.RoleID).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Rold ID is required");

Comment: What type is `RoleID`? You can use `NotNull` or `NotEmpty` [validators](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators).

Comment: @Zabavsky int, sorry I forgot add the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for [Built in Validators](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators).

You can use `NotEmpty`:

> Ensures that the specified property is not null, an empty string or whitespace (or the default value for value types, eg 0 for int)

```
RuleFor(u => u.RoleID).NotEmpty()
```

or make the property nullable and use `NotNull`:

> Ensures that the specified property is not null.

```
RuleFor(u => u.RoleID).NotNull()
```

Comment: Should we also check if specific ID exists in the database? So that FK is not violated?